# How to create an extra column and import relative paths of the images for every row of data

Tags: xml, windows, excel, automation, excel-2007

**Edit**: [Example(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IkDU.png)

I have an excel file with 1000 rows of data and a folder with 1000 images for each row of that data.

Images are in their own folder and excel doesn't have a column that associates each corresponding image to every row of data.

Is there a way to avoid inputting 1000 of relative paths manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing I can think of is to create the XML from excel and then parse the XML and add the image tags. There many options for parsing XML depending on what you are most comfortable with. There are XML parsing libraries in C#, java etc.

Parsing is when you take a bunch of symbols in interpret then as some kind of structure. In this case you would be taking the xml file and turning it into a tree of tags. Then you could go through that tree and to each item you could add an image. You would look at the name, generate the path, check for the existence of the file to verify the extension, and add it to the tree. Then you write the tree back out to file.

This is all done using a library like XmlReader in C#.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse XML"?